# Are there known error bounds for TD(0) with a constant learning rate?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods

Is there any known error bounds for the TD(0) algorithm for the value function after a finite number of iterations?

$$ \Delta_t=\max_{s \in \mathcal{S}}|v_t(s)-v_\pi(s)|$$
$$v_{t+1}(s_t)=v_t(s_t)+\alpha(r+v_t(s_{t+1})-v_t(s_t))$$

Answer (score 1):

The paper ["Bias-Variance" Error Bounds for Temporal Difference Updates](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/tdlambda.pdf) (2000) by M. Kearns and S. Singh provides error bounds for temporal-difference algorithms, i.e. TD($k$) and TD($\lambda$) (see [theorem 1](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/tdlambda.pdf#page=3) and [theorem 2](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/tdlambda.pdf#page=5), respectively). Note that both TD($k$) and TD($\lambda$) include TD($0$) as a special case.

Comment: I'm confused, is this for situations where the environment states can be enumerated or does it apply in general? I didn't see a parametrization.

Comment: @FourierFlux Do you mean if they assume that the state space is discrete? I need to read this paper again. It was a long time ago that I skimmed through it.